# Am I right in thinking modern usage of the word "me" is drifting to "I"; Is there an increasing trend?

Tags: personal-pronouns

**In reply to suggested duplicate question: It may be that I can find some useful guidance from the earlier Answer (for which thanks), but I'm really asking whether there's a general trend, particularly in the everyday speech of well-educated people, in misuse of "I" for "me", rather than explanations of individual instances.**

Nowadays, people often (usually, even) use "I" when my intuition as a native English speaker (physical scientist; by no means a grammarian) tells me they should be using "me" - even not-so-young humanities graduates from top universities are doing this.

If this is indeed ungrammatical, then perhaps people are acquiring a fear of referring to themselves using "me", as if that is somehow betraying a sense of excessive self-regard, even though "I" serves the same function...?

A PhD colleague today wrote: "Having a test available for Julia and I to review would be helpful."

If this is simplified to: "Having a test available for I to review would be helpful." seems quite wrong to me.

Are a great many other people wrong? **Or is it "I" who is wrong?** (Though I must confess I'm now not so certain about "I" in this latter example.)

Comment: In light of your edit, I've retracted my close vote and have supplied an answer to the re-focused question.

Comment: It is not only "I". I too frequently hear something like "between he and the tree".

Comment: I think you should say either "is it **I** who **am** wrong" or else "is it **me** who **is** wrong." But that's just my intuition, I'm no grammarian either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that this is a new trend, and introduce as evidence the following:

> Sweet Bassanio, my ships have all 
>   miscarried, my creditors grow cruel, my estate is 
>   very low, my bond to the Jew is forfeit; and since 
>   in paying it, it is impossible I should live, all 
>   debts are cleared **between you and I**, if I might but 
>   see you at my death

- Shakespeare, Merchant of Venice, [III, 2], 1600

So then all us 'people who are wrong' are in good company at least. In seriousness, I think that the use of "and I", right or wrong, has been a common usage for centuries; although it is a usage often regarded as incorrect.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90671?rskey=rY9nkw&result=16#eid1074466) provides further insight in this regard:

> Entry "I": Used for the objective case after a verb or preposition when separated from the governing word by other words (esp. in coordinate constructions with another pronoun and and).
>   **This has been common at various times (esp. towards the end of the 16th and in the 17th cent., and from the mid 20th cent. onwards); it has been considered ungrammatical since the 18th cent.**

The oldest usage they cite is 1582: "So after certaine familiar behauiour, vsed betweene him and I, he..went into the Refectorium"

Comment: Mark, Thank you for the data points over the last few centuries, and especially that “it has been considered ungrammatical since the 18th cent.” Perhaps my sense of a trend is more to do with listening more closely to others in recent years – a trend in my own awareness rather than in common usage.